# React.js function component useState related questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access state data.

How do I copy an `array object` I have into a `data array`?

[image]

-code

```
function TableList() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: '로트번호', field: 'lote_id' },
      { title: '중량(kg)', field: 'item_weight' },
      { title: '수량', field: 'item_quantity' },
      { title: '제품코드', field: 'item_code' },
      { title: '제품명', field: 'item_name' },
      { title: '규격', field: 'standard' },
      { title: '재질', field: 'material' },
      { title: '공정명', field: 'process_name' },
      { title: '단중', field: 'unitweight' },
      { title: '납기일시', field: 'duedate' },
      { title: '단가', field: 'item_cost' },
      { title: '금액', field: 'item_price' },
    ],
    data: [],
  });


  useEffect(() =>{
    console.log("실행")
    console.log(state.data);

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/item/1')
    .then( response => {
         //I want to copy the data of my output.list to state.data.
    })
    .catch( response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  });
```

I want to copy my axios response data into the data array declared as useState.
Please tell me the most effective way.

1. How do I access the second argument, state.data?
2. I want to access and put my output.list response data.

Comment: can you please add your code rather than an image of it?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after. Could you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: You mean you want to copy ```columns``` or some other array into ```data```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally clear on what you're looking for, but if you just want to update the `data` prop on your state object, you can do it like this:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newState.data = arrayOfObjects;
setState(newState);
```

Comment: Thank you

By the way

     axios.get ('http: // localhost: 8080 / api / item / 1')
     .then (response => {
       //console.log(response);
       var output = response && response.data;
      
       const newState = Object.assign ({}, state);
       newState.data = output.list;
       setState (newState);
     })
     .catch (response => {
       console.log (response);
     })

When you write it like this, the output occurs several times.

Comment: You'd need to post the full code for the component to see where/how you are calling it.

Comment: useEffect(() =>{
    console.log("실행")
    console.log(state.data);
    
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/item/1')
    .then( response => {
      //console.log(response);
      var output = response && response.data;
      
      const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.data = output.list;
      setState(newState);
    })
    .catch( response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  });

Comment: What function does the mounted () function of Vue.js in React.js?

Comment: Please add it to your answer, it's very tough to read like that.

Comment: Sorry, I posted it in the answer

Comment: If you want ```useEffect``` to run only once on mount, you have to pass it an empty dependency array as the second argument. Currently it will run on every render. Relevant docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great way to use useState.

```
const [columns,setColumns] = React.useState([bla,bla]);
const [data, setData] = React.useState([bla, bla]);
```

You should declare your state variables separately like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() =>{
    console.log("실행")
    console.log(state.data);

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/item/1')
    .then( response => {
      //console.log(response);
      var output = response && response.data;

      const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.data = output.list;
      setState(newState);
    })
    .catch( response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  });
```

I want to call it just once like the mounted function